# Unable to install hawtio feature in apache-karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, hawtio

I Use the following 2 commands to install the hawtio feature in apache karaf

> features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.17/xml/features
>   features:install hawtio

When I run "features:install hawtio" I get the following error

> "Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-osgi-jmx/1.4.17 in feature(s) hawtio-core-1.4.17: Activator start error in bundle io.hawt.hawtio-osgi-jmx [286]"

Could you help me fix this.

Comment: You need to provide much more information such as which Karaf version you use etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong Java version, I was using 1.6.x the compatible version for hawtio 1.4.17 is Java 1.7.x

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me

```
davsclaus:/opt/apache-karaf-2.3.7/$ bin/karaf
        __ __                  ____
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/

  Apache Karaf (2.3.7)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'osgi:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.17/xml/features
karaf@root> features:install hawtio
karaf@root> web:list
   ID   State         Web-State       Level  Web-ContextPath           Name
[  86] [Active     ] [Deployed   ]  [   80] [/hawtio                 ] hawtio :: hawtio-web (1.4.17)
[  88] [Active     ] [Deployed   ]  [   80] [/hawtio-karaf-terminal  ] hawtio :: Karaf terminal plugin (1.4.17)
karaf@root>
```

And btw there is shortcut to add hawtio, by

```
 features:chooseurl hawtio 1.4.17
```

So you need to check the logs what is failing for you, you can use `log:display` or check the data/logs directory of Apache Karaf.